# log4j2 ConfigurationFactory @Plugin discovery doesn't work in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logging, plugins, configuration, log4j2

I'm trying to configure a log4j2 custom ConfigurationFactory which initializes appenders and loggers using dynamic configuration sources.

I've followed the documentation on this subject (here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html) using @Plugin and have written some unit tests to validate my assumptions.

When I compile/run the unit tests (via Gradle+TestNG), my @Plugin annotated ConfigurationFactory is discovered and used by log4j2 as a configuration source. But when I try to run the tests in Eclipse with the TestNG plugin, log4j2 never discovers my ConfigurationFactory.

**Update**:

The issue appears to be that Log4j2Plugins.dat - which gets generated during the compile of my @Plugin annotated class - is not generated when Eclipse compiles my @Plugin annotated class.

I've hacked around the issue while running the tests in Eclipse by adding the generated Log4j2Plugins.dat file to

```
src/test/resources/META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins
```

I'd like to try to come up with a better solution to get Eclipse's compiler to do the annotation processing so that I don't have to check this generated file into my tests to make them work.